# Remove multiple records serverside with ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to delete multiple tables with a same class name,  my js code snippet works once and it doesn't loop to the next table unless the page is refreshed again.

when I comment my ajax call and just run it plain jquery it works fine. , I think there's an issue with my ajax call somewhere....

This jsfiddle url http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/ExnkV/ has the snippet without the ajax....how do I make sure the ajax call works properly rather refreshing my page every time?

```
$(".closeprod").live("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        elem = $(this).parents('.tbl');
        //get serial number         
        prodsn = $(".tbl").find(".prodsn:eq(0)");
        sn = $(prodsn[0]).html().substr(5);
                    tpl = "anything";

        url = "delprod.asp?email=<%=email%>&sn=" + sn + "&t=" + tpl + "&nf=notfeatured";
        //remove product from xml file
        $.get(url, function(data,status){
            if (data == "OK") {
                //remove product from template                  
                elem.remove();
            }else{

            alert("opps something is wrong")
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: what is ``tpl`` variable you are not assigning it any value

Comment: tpl and sn as (serial number) are coming a serverside....in this case it could be anything, I just modified my code. it's strange it only deletes once, but when i refresh the page it can delete again... i think the js cant find the multiple sn

Comment: try to put some values for them to make ajax call work and which returns some reponse

Comment: i do get a "success" response when i delete one table, but then i dont when i want to delete the next table....but after i refresh the page i can do so again....

Comment: can you make your jsfiddle ajax call work??

Comment: there are a lot of code in there ASP Classic xml and js and my data is internal.

Comment: then you need to figure it out as table removal code is fine of jquery, debug yourself via alerts of console.log to figure out

Comment: ok I figured it out this line  prodsn = $(".tbl").find(".prodsn:eq(0)"); should be prodsn = elem.find(".prodsn:eq(0)"); and it worked like this

Comment: yes it should be that way but i was not aware what is the purpose of using $(".tbl") if you had mentioned in question or code comments that you are trying to get its parent table then that would be less time consuming and you had got answer in right time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out this line prodsn = $(".tbl").find(".prodsn:eq(0)"); should be prodsn = elem.find(".prodsn:eq(0)"); and it worked like this